# How to apply theme with dropdownlist selected value?

Tags: asp.net, themes

I want to select dropdownlist values then change theme.
 Two theme Green and Red

In my code, I try to select values in dropdownlist then it redirect to first values

Ex..
    first already selected value is Green
    next select red value then it is dispaly Green in dropdownlist

following code:

```
protected void Page_PreInit(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (!IsPostBack)
    {

        if (Session["theme"] != null)
        {
            Page.Theme = Session["theme"].ToString();
        }
        Page.Theme = "Green";
    }


}
protected void ddltheme_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Session["theme"] = ddltheme.SelectedValue;
    Response.Redirect(Request.FilePath);
}
```

Comment: mhh, don't understand very well your point. Could you try to clarify? Is your problem that the dropdown doesn't keep the selection?

Answer (score 0):

You can try with

```
Session.Add("theme", ddltheme.SelectedValue);
```

And in your delegate add , because when you post data, you don't pass by your (! IsPostBack), so you don't referesh

```
Page.Theme = ddltheme.SelectedValue;

protected void ddltheme_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Session["theme"] = ddltheme.SelectedValue;
    Page.Theme = ddltheme.SelectedValue;
    Response.Redirect(Request.FilePath);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Doing the following isn't really accomplishing anything because you're just overwriting your session value:

```
if (Session["theme"] != null)
{
    Page.Theme = Session["theme"].ToString();
}
Page.Theme = "Green";
```

If anything, you're trying to default, so put it like this:

```
Page.Theme = "Green";
if (Session["theme"] != null)
{
    Page.Theme = Session["theme"].ToString();
}
```

Also, I'm not quite understanding the Response.Redirect(Request.FilePath); part... what are you trying to accomplish with this? Are you trying to run the code by way of not executing a post back? A better way would be to simply set your Page.Theme in your ddl's event as Candie has explained and not do a Response.Redirect.